# Render new ActiveRecord results using AJAX - potentially Mustache?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord, mustache

I have a standard index view that iterates through the result of an ActiveRecord query from the controller: `@recipes = Recipe.all` and displays the attributes.

```
#index.html.haml
    - @recipes.each do |recipe|
        .card-item      
            .crop= image_tag(recipe.image.url, class: "thumbnail")
            = link_to(recipe) do
                %p.card-title= recipe.title
```

I'm trying to implement a filtering feature on this page whereby a user can narrow the search results and the page will update without a reload. I've written a new route that, when hit by a filter submission, takes the parameters passed and makes a new ActiveRecord query, e.g. `@results = Recipe.where("favorite": true)`

I'm stuck on how to render the results of this query without reloading the page. After researching it, it seems like a JavaScript partial or Mustache templating as the AJAX response may be helpful, but I'm not sure about how to implement it. This seems like a pretty basic feature, so I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do it simply using built-in Rails functionality. Rebuilding the same structure from the index view in the JS file/AJAX response seems possible but not DRY or efficient (in this small case it's okay, but I can't imagine that apps that have lots more information than here do it that way). I'm basically wondering what the best solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create a partial `_recipe.html.haml`

**app/views/recipes/_recipe.html.haml**

```
.card-item      
        .crop= image_tag(recipe.image.url, class: "thumbnail")
        = link_to(recipe) do
          %p.card-title= recipe.title
```

`render` it in a section where you want on index page without `ajax` call.

**app/views/recipes/index.html.haml**

```
##Section where you want to list all recipes
%div#all_recipes
  = render @recipes
```

Assuming you perform your search in `search` action

```
def search
  @recipes = Recipe.where(favorite: true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Create a `search.js.erb` file and render the partial with the search result

**app/views/recipes/search.js.erb**

```
$("#all_recipes").html("<%= j render @recipes %>")
```

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. However, it looks like the search.js.erb file isn't being hit. I've tried putting some console-logging in to test, and it doesn't work (in addition to the filtered results not being rendered). There's no error in the console, and the server log doesn't show any action when I click the filter. Do I need to include that file anywhere directly or call it in some way?  **EDIT** I re-added the AJAX call but without doing anything in the response and it works!